# Terrestrial POWs sent to prison camp, change other extra-terrestrial prisoner's behaviors and feelings about being POWs

Tags: story-identification

It's an old novel, read long time ago.

During a long, interspecies war some Terrestrial officers, now POWs, are sent to a prison camp and change other (extra-terrestrial) prisoner's behaviors and feelings about being POWs.

The interaction with other species is comic and ironic. At the end of the story they conquer the camp and deal with the ex-guardians, changing their behaviors, too!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year or decade did you read this story? Also, am I correct in thinking that this could've been either a novel or a short story?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: It sounds a bit like Eric Frank Russell's "The Space Willies" AKA "Plus X".

Comment: If my answer it correct then it is actually a duplicate: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/155581/70s-80s-novella-humans-foment-uprising-on-pow-planet-in-order-to-win-intergala/155675

Comment: @EikePierstorff Agreed. I took one look at the question, and thought, "Didn't I already answer that one, once upon a time?" Then I followed your link and saw that was where I'd previously answered it.

Comment: @Lorendiac, I regularly forget how this stack deals with duplicates (I seem to dimly remember that both answers need to be accepted or something like it?). It's a bit awkward to see that your much more thorough answer earns less reputation, and it would be much nicer if we could redirect the votes there.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answers! Sorry to find out it was already answered, but I didn't find it.

Answer (score 27):

That is quite probably Eric Frank Russell's "[Nuisance Value](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55726)" (1957). Every species in the Galaxy is aware that a prisoner of war has no right and can do nothing but to obey the orders of their captors - every species except humans, who infiltrate a POW camp and convert the inmates to their unconventional point of view, to wit that prisoners are still people and can fight for their freedom. In the end, they take the former guards prisoner before adding them to the rank of the newly formed inter-species alliance.

Comment: If every other species in the galaxy came to accept this, maybe there was a good reason and changing behaviors on this might be a bad idea. Maybe when they realize you won't obey orders of captors they stop taking prisoners.

Comment: Thanks a lot! the very story!

Comment: @TheBoogeyman If this answer is correct, you can check the green mark next to this answer to help other users looking for this novel.